# Regridding Python xarray coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have some dummy data at 0.2 and 1 degree resolution. I would like to subsample foo to the same scale as foo1.
Is there any easy way to average and regrid my lat and long coordinates somehow?

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Set at 0.2 degree grids ish
freq=20
lats=240
lons=1020
time=pd.date_range('2000-01',periods=freq,freq='Y')
data=np.random.rand(freq,lats,lons)
lat=np.linspace(-19.5,19.5,lats)
lon=np.linspace(120,290,lons)
foo = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[time, lat,lon], dims=['time', 'lat','lon'])
foo.sel(time='2005',method='nearest').plot()
plt.show()


#Set at 1 degree grids
freq1=20
lats1=40 #Factor of 6 difference
lons1=170
time1=pd.date_range('2000-01',periods=freq1,freq='Y')
data1=np.random.rand(freq1,lats1,lons1)
lat1=np.linspace(-19.5,19.5,lats1)
lon1=np.linspace(120,290,lons1)
foo1 = xr.DataArray(data1, coords=[time1, lat1,lon1], dims=['time', 'lat','lon'])


foo1.sel(time='2005',method='nearest').plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you post your expected output

Comment: I would but I am unable to calculate it thus the question. I am hoping to average every cell (6*6=26) in foo to the scale of foo1, so the grid sizes are equal for a comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xarray can linearly interpolate latitudes and longitudes as if they were cartesian coordinates (as in your example above), but that isn't the same a proper geographical regridding. For that, you probably want to check out [xesmf](https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I decided the easiest way would be to interp using the foo1 grid.

Thus:

```
foo2=foo.interp(lat=lat1).interp(lon=lon1)
foo2.sel(time='2005',method='nearest').plot()
```

Should produce an accurate subsampled gridded map.